# Error while creating new case from chat transcript detail page

Tags: liveagent, chat, livechattranscript

We are facing error when trying to create a New case from Chat Transcript detail page even for system administrators.

Error : unable to find the what you are looking for, please contact system admin.

Error is more like the same above.

Dow we need to give any permission to be able create a new case from chat transcript detail page ?

[image]

Error screenshot when try to create new case:

[image]

Comment: [SFDC Help doc on this topic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=live_agent_attach_records_to_transcripts.htm&type=5) - user needs permissions: `Create on Case` and `Create on Live Chat Transcript`

Comment: We have these permissions enabled, but still we are unable to create a case, error message added in question details

Comment: Anything in the debug log?

Comment: No nothing in the logs.

Comment: Please do the needful

Comment: does this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/108547/automatically-associate-chat-transcript-to-case-and-account/139297) from the esteemed Doug Ayers help? as you are not using prechat I presume

Comment: Yes this is one way of doing, but we need this to be done with Deployment API only